# How to set an arbitrary variable as global in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, global-variables

How do you dynamically set variables as global in Python 3 functions?
Something like this:

```
def func1(i):
    global i
    #Some operation on i
```

How would I get the global variable to set whatever pre-existing variable is passed into the function? Such that:

```
func1(foo)
```

Would preform the operation on the variable `foo` globally rather than creating a new global variable called `i`?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this?  `foo = func1(foo)` is a much better solution most (all?) cases.  There are some horrible hacks with stack frames that I think can do this, but I've made my living for the past 15 years writing Python, and I've never needed them.

Comment: When you call a function defined as `func1(i)`, you are NOT passing a variable to it - you are passing a *value*.  Perhaps that value came from a variable, but there is absolutely no connection from the value to any variable(s) that might have held it.

Comment: Okay, the input being a value instead of the variable itself is exactly what I was hoping against. I essentially want to have: func(#Some Memory Address or variable) to create the output and directly push it to whatever the variable used as input was.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, your problem is: 
I've bound a name to some object at module level; now I want to write a function that changes the binding of that global name to another object passed as an argument to the function.

In Python global names can be referenced inside a function (provided that you don't bind another object to the same name), but to change their binding you must first declare those names as `global`. The reason is simple: by default all names bound inside a function have function scope.

```py
GLOBAL_NAME = 12
ANOTHER_GLOBAL_NAME = 50

def func(value):
    global GLOBAL_NAME
    GLOBAL_NAME = value
    print(GLOBAL_NAME, ANOTHER_GLOBAL_NAME)
```

When you call `func(33)`, `GLOBAL_NAME` will be bound to the object `33`. `ANOTHER_GLOBAL_NAME` is just a reference to a global name; since that name is not bound inside the function, Python look for that name in the global scope.

For further insights on Python scope enclosing you can refer to the Python documentation on [the global statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement), to [PEP-0227](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/) and to [PEP-3104](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/).